# Работа с двумерный массивом в представлении

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Изучаю asp. Net mvc и решил попробовать выполнить тривиальную задачу.

1. Вывести в представлении двумерный массив
2. По нажатию кнопки с ним должна выполняться например операция транспонирования и вместо текущего массива вывести на той же странице транспонировпнный массив

Массив я вывел через viewbag, как дальше с ним работать? Переменной которой я присваивают в контроллере становиться null

Comment: Слухи о "тривиальности" задачи оказались сильно преувеличенными :). Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос код и маркап.

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас нет возможности добавить код, мне поможет если ответите на вопрос почему если я в контроллере создаю глобальную переменную и присваиваю ей значение в одном методе действия, то при вызове ее в другом методике действия значение ее становиться null?

Answer (score 0):

> если я в контроллере создаю глобальную переменную и присваиваю ей
>   значение в одном методе действия, то при вызове ее в другом методе
>   действия значение ее становится `null`?

Уверен, что за названием "глобальная переменная" скрывается член класса контроллера. Для каждого запроса, обрабатываемого на сервере, создаётся новый объект (инстанс) контроллера, который ничего не знает о значениях полей других контроллеров того же типа, которые отработали раньше или параллельно обрабатывают другие запросы.